# Segmentation fault when working with 3d vector and openmp with c++

Tags: c++, vector, 3d, segmentation-fault, openmp

I am getting segmentation faults and I have no idea what is wrong.
It's my first time using openmp and have litle experience with 3d and also large vectors.

I used the icpc -openmp main.cpp to compile on Linux with no errors but when I run the code I get segmentation fault(core dumped)

I have a 3d grid that is 512 by 512 by 512 and nAtoms with with x,y,z coordinates and energy value stored in the atoms array. I want to calculate the effect of the atoms on the gridpoints.

Did I declare the vector corectly? Do I have to allocate memory to grid3d? Is the opnemp clause wrong?

If i let the loops go to 512 I get segmentation-fault so I tried going to 10 in the x,y,z for loops to not waste time and I get 0(which is wrong) for the value of the gridpoint that is printed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main (){

    int depth = 512;  //x
    int height = 512; //y
    int width = 512;  //z
    vector<vector<vector<float> > > grid3d (height, vector<vector<float> > (width, vector<float> (depth,0.0f)));

    int i=0,j=0,nAtoms;
    fstream f("atoms.txt");
    float x;
    f>>nAtoms;
    float atoms[nAtoms][4];

    while (f >> x){
        if(j<4){
            atoms[i][j]=x;
            j++;
        } else{
            j=0;i++;
            atoms[i][j]=x;
            j++;
        }
    }

    float val;
#pragma omp parallel for private(val)
    for(int x=0;x<depth;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<height;y++){
            for(int z=0;z<width;z++){
                val=0;
                for(int i=0;i<nAtoms;i++){
                    val+=(atoms[i][3])/(abs(x-atoms[i][0])+abs(y-atoms[i][1])+(z-atoms[i][2]));
                }
                grid3d[x][y][z]=val;
            }
        }
    }
// the value for some grid points should be printed
    cout<<grid3d[1][2][3]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you allocating an array to nAtoms when it isn't even a constant? and are you sure f is indeed open before you try to read from it?

Comment: To begin with, C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), so the `atoms` definition is technically invalid. Some compilers have it as an extension of the language though, but try to avoid it (in favor of `std::vector`).

Comment: As for your problem, try to locate *where* the crash happens. Please take some time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Eddge while it is a poor choice of variable names, normal shadowing rules apply and `x` is just the private loop variable within the loop.

Comment: @Zulan ahh thanks for clearing that up

Comment: I can't reproduce even with making up a `atoms.txt` (please include all required inputs to reproduce in your question as part of a [mcve]!). I also can't see anything obviously wrong. However, your error handling for file I/O is lacking, invest in that, and then use a debugger to narrow down the issue.